# Need to clear recent paths on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recents

[image: Android Studio recent files]

As shown in the image, there are some paths in Android Studio export list that are no longer exists in my computer.

This list appears when I click on the icon marked with a white circle in the image.

So I need to remove these paths from the list.

Hope someone can help me doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a file named `other.xml`, in Windows that's found in `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1` (obviously the Android Studio version may differ)

You can edit the text in `<property name="file.chooser.recent.files">` to remove the offending paths, then restart Android Studio.

Comment: I searched accross c: with file explorer search and found nothing, neither file nor folder with these names

Comment: No Users folder?

Comment: The user's folder contains ".android" folder only with the follwoing files:

https://i.imgur.com/t2XBkk5.png

Also the folders ".gradle", "Emulator", "Android SDK" "Flutter SDK" are all stored on d: partition and also nothing found.

My Android Studio version is 4.1.2

Comment: It may be in C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: You may need to put C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData in the address bar as it might be hidden.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you very much for yor help.

Comment: Happy to help! Please consider upvoting or accepting if it's solved your problem :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I accepted and upvoted the answer, and this message appeared: https://i.imgur.com/gqOOjlR.png